# Cmake can not configure: Version mismatch between Python interpreter (2.7.15) and libraries (2.7.13)

Tags: python, ubuntu, cmake, root-framework

Recently I made an update on my ubuntu 18.04 and I noticed the python is updated from 2.7.13 (installed last year by `apt-get install python` after the ubuntu installation, and if I do this now I will get 2.7.15). However, when I do cmake configure for the cern ROOT software, I get:

```
-- Looking for python
CMake Error at cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:480 (message):
  Version mismatch between Python interpreter (2.7.15) and libraries
  (2.7.13).

  ROOT cannot work with this configuration.  Please specify only
  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE to CMake with an absolute path to ensure matching
  versions are found.
```

I have tried: cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python-config --prefix)/lib/libpython2.7.dylib -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python-config --prefix)/include/python2.7 
The results show that:

```
-- Looking for python
-- Found PythonLibs: /lib/libpython2.7.dylib  
CMake Error at cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:480 (message):
  Version mismatch between Python interpreter (2.7.15) and libraries ().

  ROOT cannot work with this configuration.  Please specify only
  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE to CMake with an absolute path to ensure matching
  versions are found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:150 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I think this should be a problem caused by a mismatch of python-2.7.15
interpreter and the python-2.7.13 library. I wonder how to fix it by making the python library to 2.7.15 or interpreter to 2.7.13?

Comment: You need to update `python-dev` package too. Do not forget to clear CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt`) or clean the project's **build directory** after updating.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried sudo apt-get install python-dev to get that update to 2.7.15 but still does not work.

Comment: The error message tells you to specify **only** PYTHON_EXECUTABLE. Have you tried doing that instead of specifying PYTHON_LIBRARY and PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR?

Comment: In my case, I have both python2 and python3 installed. And cmake threw this error.
I used following : cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 myCommand